# C++ DLL import class unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, class, dll, symbols

Hi I'm sorry I've seen that there is a lot of "unresolved external symbol error" questions, and I've seen them but none of the answers that I found fixed my error.

I've tested 2 ways to compile the DLL and use the HelloWorld method from SerialPort class.
btw I'm using VS2019 community edition

Both ways are throwing the same error :

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall SerialPort::HelloWorld(void)" (?HelloWorld@SerialPort@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main Test DriverCore C:\Users\$USER\source\repos\Test DriverCore\Test DriverCore\Main.obj    1
```

To what I've understood it's a linker error and the name of the method that I'm using is unresolved (not found) but I have no idea how to fix that (I thought that extern "C" prevented this to happen)

I've also tried to add `#pragma comment(lib, "DriverCore.lib")`(with DriverCore.lib in the same Dir as DriverCore.h) but still nothing :/

**Way 1**
using a function to return a pointer to the class

*DriverCore.h*

```cpp
#pragma once

#ifdef DRIVERCORE_EXPORTS
#define DLLCALL __declspec(dllexport)

#else 
#define DLLCALL __declspec(dllimport)

#endif

class SerialPort
{
private:
    bool connected = 0;
public:
    SerialPort() {};
    void HelloWorld();
    bool isConnected() { return 0; };
    int readSerialPort(char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size) { return 0; };
    bool writeSerialPort(char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size) { return 0; };
};

extern "C" { 
    DLLCALL SerialPort* __stdcall CreateSerialPort(); 
};
```

*DriverCore.cpp*

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "DriverCore.h"
#include <iostream>
#define DRIVERCORE_EXPORTS


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,DWORD ul_reason_for_call,LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}

SerialPort* __stdcall CreateSerialPort()
{
    return new SerialPort();
}

void SerialPort::HelloWorld()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World !";
}
```

*Main.cpp*

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "DriverCore.h"

typedef SerialPort* (__stdcall *SerialPortImported) ();

int main()
{
    // instantiate the dll location
    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibraryW(L"DriverCore.dll"); 
    if (!hDLL) {
        std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    //Resolve Objects Addr
    SerialPortImported pCSerialPort = (SerialPortImported) GetProcAddress(hDLL, "CreateSerialPort") ;
    SerialPort* CSerialPort = pCSerialPort();
    CSerialPort->HelloWorld();

    return 0;
}
```

**Way 2**
without using extern "c" {...} but using __declspec directly onto the class declaration

*DriverCore.h*

```cpp
#pragma once

#ifdef DRIVERCORE_EXPORTS
#define DLLCALL __declspec(dllexport)

#else 
#define DLLCALL __declspec(dllimport)

#endif

class DLLCALL SerialPort
{
private:
    bool connected = 0;
public:
    SerialPort() {};
    void HelloWorld();
    bool isConnected() { return 0; };
    int readSerialPort(char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size) { return 0; };
    bool writeSerialPort(char* buffer, unsigned int buf_size) { return 0; };
};
```

*DriverCore.cpp*

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "DriverCore.h"
#include <iostream>
#define DRIVERCORE_EXPORTS


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,DWORD ul_reason_for_call,LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}

void SerialPort::HelloWorld()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World !";
}
```

*Main.cpp*

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "DriverCore.h"

int main()
{
    // instantiate the dll location
    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibraryW(L"DriverCore.dll");
    if (!hDLL) {
        std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //Resolve Objects Addr
    SerialPort* pSerialPort = (SerialPort*) GetProcAddress(hDLL, "SerialPort") ;
    pSerialPort->HelloWorld();

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You need to define `DRIVERCORE_EXPORTS` before `#include "DriverCore.h"`

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes I've replaced it, thanks ! But it didn't fix the error

Comment: This should have worked for example #2.

Comment: @drescherjm i haven't tested with the 2nd way,so it changes the unresolved external symbol from ```public: void __thiscall SerialPort::HelloWorld(void)```to ```__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall SerialPort::HelloWorld(void) ```

Comment: That error is telling you to link to the import library in your test application. I don't use explicit linking with dlls so I am not sure I can help remove this dependency.

Comment: Related: [http://codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/dll/importexportissues/article.php/c123/Explicitly-Linking-to-Classes-in-DLLs.htm](http://codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/dll/importexportissues/article.php/c123/Explicitly-Linking-to-Classes-in-DLLs.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `HelloWorld` which is missing its implementation in your application.

There is some fundamental misunderstanding about how C++ executables are compiled and linked against DLLs.

#### No libraries:

- All symbols that the Application needs must be defined in the Application.
- **All needed symbol definitions must be available to the linker.**

#### Static libraries:

- All symbols that the Application needs must be defined in the Application or a static library.
- **All needed symbol definitions must be available to the linker.**
- The symbols are added to the generated Application's executable.

#### Dynamic libraries:

- All symbols that the Application needs must be defined in the Application or a dynamiclibrary.
- **All needed symbol definitions must be available to the linker.**
- The symbols remain at their original places and they are loaded only at load time. This allows swap the dynamic libraries with any other ABI-compatible one at load time.

Since you are not linking with the dll and only load it at runtime, the linker correctly complains about the missing `HelloWorld` method.

Extern "C" is irrelevant here.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer ! While doing ```class DLLCALL SerialPort {..}``` am I not declaring the SerialPort class symbol and all his methods ?

Comment: @Rzdhop Declaring - yes, so the compiler does not complain; defining - no, so the linker does complain. Actually you are defining all of them inline with the exception of `HelloWorld`. That is the reason why it is the only method the linker complains about.

Comment: @Rzdhop "*declaring the SerialPort class symbol*" There exists no such symbol. An exported *object* of type `SerialPort` will have a corresponding symbol, and so will a member function of `SerialPort`. But the class itself is a compile-time construct, not a runtime one, and there is no "*symbol*" associated with it. That's why `GetProcAddress(hDLL, "SerialPort")` will return NULL, which btw you should check for in the code before attempting to use that return value.